# How to create popup in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, newsletter, popup, modal-popup, modal

Sometimes it is required like to show promotional popup for the first time when customer visits the site. How to create popup based on cookie in magento 2? Like I want to display any CMS static block in popup.

Comment: Why author of accepted answer didn't mention
that solution is taken from here: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-how-to-display-static-block-content-in-modal-overlay/ ?

Comment: Stolen is a big word :P But agree, he could put credit to the author.

Comment: I agree, it is corrected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139927)

Comment: I recently have installed Magento 2.3 via Composer. I want to implement this modal popup on the home page. I followed the above steps, but I guess I am missing something. After creating the folders and files with the above content, I ran these commands sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy I'm wondering what I have done wrong. Can anybody point or guide me out in the right direction?
I'm getting the home page displayed with no content at the moment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is very simple to create modal popup in Magento 2. Like if you want to display any static block in popup, you can do it simply by calling the content and displaying it.

We should start by creating new module in Magento 2.

> 1. app/code/Example/ModalOverlay/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Example_ModalOverlay',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/Example/ModalOverlay/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Example_ModalOverlay" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/Example/ModalOverlay/Block/ModalOverlay.php

```
namespace Example\ModalOverlay\Block;

use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class ModalOverlay extends Template
{

    private $blockRepository;

    public function __construct(
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getContent($identifier)
    {
        try {
            /** @var BlockInterface $block */
            $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($identifier);
            $content = $block->getContent();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $content = false;
        }

        return $content;
    }
}
```

> 4. app/code/Example/ModalOverlay/view/frontend/templates/modal_overlay.phtml

```
<?php if ($content = $block->getContent('any-cms-block-indetifier-to-be-displayed')) { ?>

    <div id="modal-overlay" style="display:none;">
        <?php echo $content ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "modal_overlay": {
                            "component": "Example_ModalOverlay/js/modal_overlay"
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    </script><?php } ?>
```

> 5. app/code/Example/ModalOverlay/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Example\ModalOverlay\Block\ModalOverlay"
                   template="Example_ModalOverlay::modal_overlay.phtml"
                   name="modalOverlay"
                   as="modalOverlay"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 6. app/code/Example/ModalOverlay/view/frontend/web/js/modal_overlay.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, $, modal, storage) {
    'use strict';

    var cacheKey = 'modal-overlay';

    var getData = function () {
        return storage.get(cacheKey)();
    };

    var saveData = function (data) {
        storage.set(cacheKey, data);
    };

    if ($.isEmptyObject(getData())) {
        var modal_overlay = {
            'modal_overlay': false
        };
        saveData(modal_overlay);
    }

    return Component.extend({

        initialize: function () {

            this._super();
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: false,
                title: false,
                buttons: false
            };

            var modal_overlay_element = $('#modal-overlay');
            var popup = modal(options, modal_overlay_element);

            modal_overlay_element.css("display", "block");

            this.openModalOverlayModal();

        },

        openModalOverlayModal:function(){
            var modalContainer = $("#modal-overlay");

            if(this.getModalOverlay()) {
               return false;
            }
            this.setModalOverlay(true);
            modalContainer.modal('openModal');
        },

        setModalOverlay: function (data) {
            var obj = getData();
            obj.modal_overlay = data;
            saveData(obj);
        },

        getModalOverlay: function () {
            return getData().modal_overlay;
        }

    });
});
```

It's done.

[image]

Comment: 1+ for you. Good work.

Comment: Can u please tell me what is use of `storage.key` at this pop?

Comment: I tried The above Process But i haven't got anything.Like pop @Kazim Noorani

Comment: Popup is not showing @Kazim Noorani

Comment: Can you please post your code? @PranayK

Comment: Same Code that You have posted. @KazimNoorani

Comment: is there any way to trigger this popup only on cart page? @KazimNoorani

Comment: Yes definitely. You directly render one .phtml file on checkout_cart_index layout page. And in that .phtml file, you can call your modal popup. @user3189566

Comment: @KazimNoorani  any idea about this implementation https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245983/magento-2-need-to-display-the-popup-in-checkout-when-product-is-orderedqty-is-gr?noredirect=1#comment344769_245983

Comment: @KazimNoorani at least you could write the source of your sollution. This is a copy paste with minor naming changes form Inchoo website https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-how-to-display-static-block-content-in-modal-overlay/

Comment: Great Job! Work perfectly!

Comment: My pop up isn't loading upm I dont get any errors either. anyone help